# Bootstrap tooltip is not working on my php file

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-modal

I have using bootstrap  v3.3.7 on for my php project. I have included all minified files. But my tooltip is not working.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
 
})
   </script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="content1">
      <div style="padding-left:120px; padding-right:120px">
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post"
      id="formID" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name of business</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control validate[required]"  placeholder="Enter name of your business" name="tbname" value="<?=$b_name?>" >
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
          <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Area</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <select class="form-control" name="area" id="area" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="specify your nearby location">
        <option value="">-- Select Area --</option>
    <?php

        $q = mysqli_query($con, "select * from tbl_areas");
        while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
        {
          
            echo "<option value='$result[areaid]'>$result[area]</option>";
        }
        ?>
        </select>
       </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7"> <input type="submit" name="btnad" id="btnad" value="Register" class="btn btn-info"/></div>

</form>
</div>
    </div> 
 </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="right">
        <?php include 'include\front_right.php'?>
      </div>
    </div>
</div><!--row end-->
   

</div>
```

I have used here tooltip for only 'select' tag. but still not working.
Please give me solution for this.

Comment: first of all add jQery and bootstrap library in head tag and then call tooltip() function in footer of the page
Since you are not using any ajax call to add select Tag then above suggestion will help you to resolve the issue.
In case of Ajax call you might have to use jQuery dynamic binding .

Answer (score 1):

Please chekc this demo how it is working

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please insert your code as `<select class="form-control" name="area" id="area" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="specify your nearby location">
</select>`

Comment: No problem. Just google search you can find all the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you included jquery?
Here is a working example:

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Area</label>
    
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <select class="form-control" name="area" id="area" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="specify your nearby location">
          <option value="">-- Select Area --</option>
          <option value="1">Area 1</option>
          <option value="2">Area 2</option>
        </select>
       </div>
    
    </div>
  </div>
```